# Errors arises when implement merge sort in python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to implement merge sort in python as following:

```
def MergeSortTopdown(list_n):
     #Base condition to stop recursion
    if len(list_n) == 1:
        return list_n
    else:
        mid = int(len(list_n)/2)
        first_half = list_n[:mid]
        second_half = list_n[mid:]
        MergeSortTopdown(first_half)
        MergeSortTopdown(second_half)
        i = 0
        j = 0 
        n = len(list_n)
        for k in range(n):
            if j >= len(first_half) and i < len(second_half):
                list_n[k] = first_half[i]
                i += 1 
            if i >= len(first_half) and j < len(second_half): 
                list_n[k] = second_half[j]
                j += 1
            if i < len(first_half) and j < len(second_half):
                if first_half[i] > second_half[j]:
                    list_n[k] = second_half[j]
                    j += 1   
                elif second_half[j] > first_half[i]:
                    list_n[k] = first_half[i]
                    i += 1
                elif second_half[i] == first_half[j]:
                    list_n[k] = first_half[i]
                    if i>j:
                        i += 1
                    else:
                        j += 1

    return list_n
```

it seems reasonable when I tested with already sorted list. However, when I run, this error raises:

```
MergeSortTopdown([3,4,6,7,1,8,56,112,67])
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-11-29db640f4fc6>", line 1, in <module>
    MergeSortTopdown([3,4,6,7,1,8,56,112,67])

  File "C:/Users/Emmanuel Hoang/MergeSortTopDown.py", line 13, in MergeSortTopdown
    MergeSortTopdown(second_half)

  File "C:/Users/Emmanuel Hoang/MergeSortTopDown.py", line 13, in MergeSortTopdown
    MergeSortTopdown(second_half)

  File "C:/Users/Emmanuel Hoang/MergeSortTopDown.py", line 19, in MergeSortTopdown
    list_n[k] = first_half[i]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can you tell me what's wrong with my code, is there any way that I can improve my code. Thank you in advance

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've tried to reference an element past the end of the list.  I added some straightforward `print` statements to your code:

```
   for k in range(n):
        print("LOOP TOP", k, first_half, second_half, list_n)
        if j >= len(first_half) and i < len(second_half):
            print("TRACE", list_n, k, "\t", first_half, i)
            list_n[k] = first_half[i]
            i += 1
```

Then I shortened the input list to `[8,56,112,3,67]`.

Output:

```
LOOP TOP 0 [8] [56] [8, 56]
LOOP TOP 1 [8] [56] [8, 56]
LOOP TOP 0 [3] [67] [3, 67]
LOOP TOP 1 [3] [67] [3, 67]
LOOP TOP 0 [112] [3, 67] [112, 3, 67]
LOOP TOP 1 [112] [3, 67] [3, 3, 67]
TRACE [3, 3, 67] 1   [112] 0
LOOP TOP 2 [112] [3, 67] [3, 67, 67]
TRACE [3, 67, 67] 2      [112] 1
```

This is followed by the crash you got.  You try to fetch `first_half[1]` when there's only an element 0.

**ANALYSIS**

You have three successive `if` statements to check list bounds:

```
        if j >= len(first_half) and i < len(second_half):
        if i >= len(first_half) and j < len(second_half): 
        if i < len(first_half) and j < len(second_half):
```

You have `i` and `j` switched in the first check: `i` is the `first_half` subscript.  This change fixes the merge:

```
        if i < len(first_half) and j >= len(second_half):
```

**Suggestions**

Part of your problem is that your merge logic is too complex.  You have a single value check during the main part of the loop: move the lower of the list heads to the merged list.  Do this while both indices are in range.

Then, when one index hits the end of its list, drop out of the loop and add the remaining elements of the other list.  Use the `extend` method.  So ...

```
while i < len(first_half) and j < len(second_half):
    if first_half[i] < second_half[j]:
        # move smaller element to list_n;
        # increment i or j as needed
    k += 1

# One of these will be an empty operation.
list_n.extend(first_half[i:])
list_n.extend(second_half[j:])
```

Comment: finally, I see the logic why my code was complicated. I have revised my code based on your suggestions. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

### To resolve the `IndexError`:

The first case that you check for in your 'merge step' of the merge sort -- if you have already merged all elements from the list `second_half` -- has the names of your two lists `first_half` and `second_half` switched around. Instead of this:

```
if j >= len(first_half) and i < len(second_half):
    list_n[k] = first_half[i]
    i += 1
```

you should have this:

```
if j >= len(second_half) and i < len(first_half):
    list_n[k] = first_half[i]
    i += 1
```

This will correctly check for the condition specified above.

### Why this was happening:

The reason why you received an `IndexError` is because you were trying to call `first_half[i]` and were not correctly confirming that `i` was a valid index in the list `first_half` before doing so.

Comment: oh, that's simple right? thank you a lot for pointing this out for me

Comment: @EmmanuelHoang If either of the answers that you received solved your problem, please select one as the accepted answer